# path when I hit double tab

Tags: path

I am almost a newbie to command prompt control in Mac.

Yesterday, when I open terminal and hit command prompt twice. I have a very neat result showing a few truly useful stuffs... But after I instal Pycharm today and maybe the path variable has been changed, I get about 1500+ results in the bin when i double hit the tab... I just want to revert to my original neat bins but I am almost an absolute newbie and don't know what to do. Could anyone help me with this?

Also as you see, do you think there is some sort of newbie guide to use Mac as a professional computational scientist? Thank you:)

Comment: I'm getting 1594 results on pretty much a default Mavericks install (plus Xcode command-line tools).

Comment: oh... I just felt that there is a bin that contains things that are sort of more important, things like gcc+ and things I installed like gurobi and python3.4